# SSMS execution time queries besides SET STATISTICS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, statistics

When I run my query, it prints multiple execution times instead of just one. I only want one so what should I use instead of `SET STATISTICS`?

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
DECLARE @firstNum INT, @secondNum INT, @thirdNum INT, @evenSum INT
SET @firstNum = 1
SET @secondNum = 2
set @thirdNum = 2
SET @evenSum = 2
WHILE (@thirdNum <= 4000000)
BEGIN
    SET @thirdNum = @firstNum + @secondNum
    SET @firstNum = @secondNum
    SET @secondNum = @thirdNum
    IF (@thirdNum % 2) = 0
    SET @evenSum += @thirdNum
END
PRINT 'Answer = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @evenSum)
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
```

It prints this like a hundred times:

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

Comment: What specifically do you want to measure? Elapsed time from beginning to end of script? CPU consumed?

Answer (score 2):

In the "Query" menu in SSMS there is an option "Include Client Statistics" that you can look at.

There is no TSQL command like `SET STATISTICS` that prints out cumulative stats per batch.

You could of course just do

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME2 = SYSUTCDATETIME()

--Your code here 

SELECT DATEDIFF(NANOSECOND, @StartTime, SYSUTCDATETIME())
```

But on my desktop the code runs far too quickly for the resolution of `SYSUTCDATETIME()` so most of the time it returns `0`.

If you just want to know that the code runs "fast enough" to likely not need any performance tuning this may be sufficient.

For a higher resolution option you could get the value of `cpu_ticks` in `sys.dm_os_sys_info` before and after execution and try and translate this back to clock time (e.g. by getting the diff and dividing by `3,000` on a 3GHZ processor to get `μs`) but this [may not be reliable](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dont-tick-me-off-cpu-ticks).

You could also wrap the code to test into a temporary stored procedure and look at the stats collected for that

```
CREATE PROC #P AS
BEGIN
YourCodeHere:
END

GO

EXEC #P

SELECT last_execution_time,
       execution_count,
       total_worker_time  AS [total_worker_time μs],
       total_physical_reads,
       total_logical_writes,
       total_logical_reads,
       total_elapsed_time AS [total_worker_time μs]
FROM   tempdb.sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats
WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#P')
```

But probably the easiest way of getting useful timings for the original code is simply to run it in a loop for a million times and time the overall duration of that - so that any inaccuracies caused by the resolution of `SYSUTCDATETIME()` average out to become negligible.